# New Math Teaching Stackexchange is looking for 38 more people to register for a private beta

Tags: discussion, area51

Edit: Thanks to the 162 people who have signed up so far! You've made this proposal one of the fastest-growing proposals of all time.

The math teaching SE proposal has reached the commitment phase, where it needs 200 people to register for a private beta. Many proposals stall here because they can't find 200 people to participate in a private beta; there is large initial interest, and then signups die out. If you are at all interested, please sign up at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-learning-studying-and-education

The users in the private beta are supposed to ask/answer 10 questions over a period of about six months (although you can easily do this in a couple of weeks or even days).

Comment: I signed up, but it created [another account](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/103808/calvin-lin) for me. How do I get it merged?

Comment: Only moderators can merge accounts, I think. Thanks for signing up! Try contacting a moderator or searching meta for 'merge account'.

Comment: @CalvinLin You created the account as an unregistered user, if you register the account (via the "register" option at the top middle on the profile page while logged in) with the same login as you use here, it should be linked. If you have any trouble, you can reach us through the ["contact us" form](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/contact), and I'll be able to work directly with you to fix that.

Comment: What does "ask/answer" mean? We have to ask ten *and* answer ten? Or just satisfy *asked + answered* $\geq$ 10?

Comment: the second option

Comment: "Proposed Q&A site for math educators, enthusiasts, students, professors."     There seems to be overlap with the people who generally post on this Math forum.  Is the intent to be more explicitly geared towards k-12 classroom math?  Education issues and debates?

Comment: @JackOfAll It's geared towards questions about the process of teaching at any level. So questions would be like "How can I assign meaningful homework if all the solutions are online?"

Comment: That isn't a teaching question, but a question of *academic administration*, institutional bureaucracy and the like.  Construed as a teaching question the answer is trivial: the exercises are just as meaningful, and potentially more instructive, when solutions are available.  The question you appear to have in mind is, "how can I continue to effectively pressure and manipulate students to perform mathematics exercises when solutions are easily found online", which is a question of bureaucracy, methods of control and other things irrelevant to mathematics. @BrianRushton

Comment: Brian slowly backs away without making eye contact. His hands drop his list of possible questions as he disappears around the corner. @zyx picks up the list. "#2: Is electroshock therapy available for use in American academic institutions as a means of motivation?" He crumples the paper. "This is not the last time we will meet, Rushton."

Comment: The actually serious point was that the new group, if formed, will do a major dis-service if it quietly smuggles the idea of student control into the very definition of "mathematics teaching".  If such control is deemed important, the issues would be the same more or less independent of subject taught, and a generic studentcontrol.stackexchange.com proposal would be the logical thing, instead of injecting the control discussions into a math teaching forum.  Judging from the atmosphere here on meta it would be fairly popular!  @BrianRushton

Comment: @zyx You're right, there is a serious point to be made here. You can browse the complete list of sample questions (the one I mentioned was my own, and not representative of all questions). An answer like you've begun here, backed up with psychological studies or other references, belongs on some stackexchange, whether math-specific or not.

Comment: I'm not attempting to answer the question, but to point out that unless the teaching versus control distinction is addressed in the formation of the group, it is taking an ostensibly positive proposal and using it to accomplish something highly negative.  MSE and other online sites represent one new and better model for exchange of mathematical ideas, than the authoritarian evaluator-teacher mode that is all too familiar, and instead of just sticking to *teaching* the new site is baking in the authoritarian model which really should have a separate venue (and many exist). @BrianRushton

Comment: @zyx There is actually a large group of people involved in the proposal who want to make sure to avoid exactly what you're talking about. Specifically, they want to make sure that self-learners and other people in non-traditional teaching situations are represented and welcomed. You can see some of their comments in the discussion on names. quid in particular is a strong advocate of this viewpoint. My question got upvoted because some people agree with the student-control viewpoint (as you call it), and everyone else was in a rush to get the proposal started.

Comment: I read through nearly everything at the area51 proposal, and I have not seen the view advocated that the site should **reject on principle** any content pertaining to academic administration (as more suitable for academia.SE or some other site) and maintain a specific focus on questions whose answers are independent of the existence of structures for evaluation, grading, credential awarding, professional advancement and so on. Generously including the non-traditional students does not address the problem of allowing teaching-plus-control in the scope of the site rather than plain teaching.

Comment: @zyx I would recommend starting such a discussion in the are51 site and opening it up to discussion. I'm sure that some people would be very interested, including Bill Dubuque and others.

Comment: I may do that, but since the site is being promoted here (and I don't necessarily intend to register for the private beta there), this is as good a place as any for the time being.

Comment: @zyx It seems to me you are overreacting a bit. Not sure what the intent of that question is (granted perhaps it goes a bit in the direction against which you argue), *but*  the situation is changed a bit when solutions are available (even if you do not put pressure on the students). Yes, perhaps even for the better. Still it might requirer a bit of a different approach maybe. So why not ask about it. Come join the crowd as long as there are slots open. It will be great fun to figure out procedures for that site together. Even more so if we have some more opinionate people around.

Comment: @quid, there is a critical problem at the very core of the current proposal: it defines the new site in terms of **Who** (a site "for educators ... students and professors") rather than **What** (the subject matter).  As long as that is the case, it will tend to prejudice the types of users and the content posted on the site toward a mentality of institutional administration, pressure and "incentives" as discussed above, that has little connection (except, perhaps, an adverse one) with teaching mathematics.  Mixing some genuine teaching discussion with that does not remove the problem.

Comment: (of course the invitations to participate are very nice, and as I said I might do that, depending on time available and other factors, but the issues raised in the comments here seem to exist independent of whether I go and discuss them at area51).

Comment: @zyx but to some extent the "who" issue is forced upon the site by the software; every site needs a "target audience." This site here is also for "People studying mathematics at any level and professionals in related fields" (not the mathematics *itself*) so the other one could be "People teaching mathematics at any level and [...]" where the thing after the "and" could be researchers in math education or something more inclusive. Actually these are basically the existing proposals.

Comment: Mathematics is a pre-existing subject that is more or less universally recognized independent of social structures, so this problem does not affect MSE so much, whatever the one sentence description.  "Research mathematics" and "whatever teachers of mathematics do" are sociological definitions, and yes, that is just as much of a problem for MathOverflow, and with visible effects similar to the ones that can be predicted for a **Who**-based math teaching site.  For a future site the mistake can be prevented in advance. For MO, "it's complicated".  @quid

Comment: @zyx I agree that for teaching math there are more such issues than for just math. However, I am not sure I agree regaring research math and MO. Especially I think that research math is not less (at least not significantly less) recognized (or at least recognizeable, but this is orthogonal) independent of social structures. More generally, MO is not that who-based in my opinion and experience. Sure, a bit in some ways, but not overly so.

Comment: Now 40 more and then it's beta-time. Looking forward to it.

Comment: @quid, I joined only to find the worst-case scenario developing, that a site advertised (to get the commitments) by terms such as "math teaching" and "forum for chatty mathematics education questions" is now on track to name itself "Math Educators" simply because of the early-registration demographics.  Apart from validating rather clearly the concerns raised above, it ends up being a bait-and-switch in which a neutral proposal is hijacked for more specific interests.

Comment: @zyx yes the new name is not perfect. As you presumably noticed I had suggested and fought a bit for a different one, namely Mathematics Teaching and Pedagogy, in addition to raising the concern that some will find the Mathematics Educators problematic. There was however not that much opposition to it, so I did not press the matter. Personally I think the title will not be that relevant but I can see how you do not like it. I even thought about quoting your earlier comment as testimonial against the other name but ultimately decided against it.

Comment: @zyx - I am missing something, what do you see as the change's impact? Looks like name-only to me.

Comment: The name change *is* one of the impacts, of the initial 200 users being predominantly ones whose income is connected to institutional education. In the SE private beta model, additional impacts of that include what "seed" questions appear and how they are answered and voted on, construction of the FAQ and what will be deemed on- and off-topic by the time of the public beta, and above all the general set of assumptions brought to bear when posing and replying to questions ("institutionalizing" queries that do not logically require that, and other related effects) .  @JoeTaxpayer

Comment: @zyx - I am old, and perhaps dense. Not seeing difference from "math teaching" to "Math Educators". I guess we'll see more in the FAQ when on-topic and off-topic are parsed out. I have my own thoughts on what I'd bring up here, that I think are OT on the main site.

Comment: The difference is that most SE sites, research journals and serious topical forums, especially ones with free access, purport to be about a subject and not a plaything of the typical group(s) representing interest in that subject.  There is not a group for "white and Asian chess enthusiasts" or "male gamers", but rather a chess.SE and gaming.SE, even though a majority of potential users could be described in those terms. And practically nobody would consider a site "for chess professionals" to be the same as a chess site.  At any rate, I will post at the beta sometime.@JoeTaxpayer

Comment: I would certainly prefer something like "Mathematics education" to "Mathematics educators", but I would also certainly oppose the general banning of questions that zyx dislikes.

Comment: Hopefully you meant "oppose the banning of questions of the type that zyx has proposed be rejected on principle" and not the much more pejorative literal interpretation of the comment.  @Phira

Comment: [Mathematics Educators](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)  (beta)  started yesterday.

Comment: Since the post is no longer relevant, I'm voting to close.